# Multiple many to one relationships to one table

Tags: database-design, entity-framework-core, relation

It's been a while since I had to redo a whole database and I'm questioning a very basic something and I can't find the right answer by searching. Seems like I am missing something.

Three tables (working in **Entity Framework Core**)

- Clients
- Companies
- Addresses

Clients can have multiple addresses and companies can have multiple addresses, but the same address should not be related to both, so only one is allowed. And I cannot seem to find out the most rightful way to do this. For now I have two FK on Addresses so one of them is always empty but it feels odd.

Have been thinking to create ClientAddress & CompanyAddress which inherits from Address and use a table-per-hierarchy method since table-per-type is not supported yet in EF Core.. They both would have the same fields, but only the relation would be different but not sure if that's the right way either.

Any advice here?

Comment: Party model? `Client` and `Company` are parties. Subtype in DB-speak like: 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a196713%20subtype

Comment: @DamirSudarevic Client and Company are very different in our database so I can't use them as a subtype..

Comment: They are "subtypes" in the generic sense of the word. Every FK (among other things) characterizes a subtype & supertype. Read the link & google re DB/SQL subtypes/inheritance/polymorphism with site:stackoverflow.com. You also have 2 types of addresses--one for each subtype of party. Disjoint subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

Having two optional FKs for `addresses` one referencing `clients` and the other one referencing `companies`, such that one of them is NULL for any given address row, is the correct representation of an alternative (XOR-) association between an address and either a client or a company.

So, there is no need to blow up your design with an artificial distinction between "ClientAddress" and "CompanyAddress".

Comment: There is a better design. TPH/TPT with polymorphic relations.

Comment: @Jesse: Sounds like over-engineering... But if you think you know a solution, then you should present it in an answer.

Comment: Could you ellaborate a bit more why it's overengineering? Will post an answer when it's fully clear so others can benefit as well.